# Emacs -nw prints Turkish characters incorrectly

Tags: unicode

I use Emacs 25.2.1 on a Windows XP Laptop with a Turkish keyboard.

**Problem**

On `emacs -nw` the following (non-ascii) letters print incorrectly:

Letters such as '`ö`' and '`ü`' which are also used in German and letters which are presumably Roman or Polish/Slavic such as '`ç`' and those letters which are AFAIK only to be found in Turkish such as '`ğ`' and '`ı`' (i without dot)

When I open GUI Emacs there are no problems but when I open Emacs in tty mode (`emacs -nw`) when I press

```
   ş prints _
   ı prints 1 (as number)
   ğ performs the `undo` or `redo` actions
```

Also

- Other non-ascii letters common to other languages, as `ç` `ü` `ö` print all correctly.
- Using the Windows' built-in `cmd.exe` or `ConEmu` or `CMDer` for `emacs -nw` makes no difference
- Changing Windows' code page `chcp.com 1254`, `1256` or `857` doesn't help either.
- If I `chcp.com 65001` (Windows' UTF8 code) then all characters in Emacs print incorrectly.

**Note:**

When I copy and paste Turkish characters into `emacs nw` it prints them correctly. So the problem happens only when pressing the letters from the keyboard.

### Question

How to fix this problem?

Comment: I presume your terminal is not sending what you expect.  What does `C-h k` or `C-h l` say about those keys?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. `C-h k` for the `ğ` keyboard button gives: *C-_ runs the command undo (found in global-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘simple.el’. It is bound to C-_, <undo>, C-/, C-x u, <menu-bar> <edit> <undo>.* When I do `C-h l` for the `ğ` keyboard button, it does and says at the mini buffer `undo`

Comment: `C-h k` for the `ı` keyboard button gives (truncated a bit): *1 runs the command digit-argument (found in help-mode-map), which is
an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘simple.el’. It is bound to C-9, C-8, C-7, C-6, C-5, C-4, C-3, C-2, C-1, C-0, ESC
0..9, C-M-9, C-M-8, C-M-7, C-M-6, C-M-5, C-M-4, C-M-3, C-M-2, C-M-1, C-M-0, and many ordinary text characters.*

Comment: `C-h k`for the `ş` keyboard button gives (truncated a bit): * _ runs the command self-insert-command (found in global-map), which is
an interactive built-in function in ‘C source code’. It is bound to many ordinary text characters. (self-insert-command N)*

Comment: Added some notes to the original post. FYI.

Comment: These two posts are very similar to my problem: [can't type ç](https://www.reddit.com/r/spacemacs/comments/8hxu81/weird_bug_cant_type_the_character_%C3%A7_in_spacemacs) and [emacs locks hard when £ is entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674428/emacs-locks-hard-over-putty-when-%C2%A3-is-entered)